# nftables limit doesn't seem to work for some STUN requests

Tags: nftables, coturn

I'm setting up a server with coturn using only STUN (TURN is disabled). It seems that STUN UDP can be used for DDoS, so I'm trying to set `nftables` rules to make it harder, but the rules don't seem to always work. Sometimes, I can see something like this using `tcpdump`:

```
21:16:08.006842 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.007091 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.258386 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.258613 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.278988 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.279229 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.475423 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.475734 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.481217 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.481416 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.484939 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.485211 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.490332 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.490545 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.505617 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.505901 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.529745 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.530020 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
21:16:08.819766 IP 5.39.71.183.25565 > A.B.C.D.3478: UDP, length 20
21:16:08.820048 IP A.B.C.D.3478 > 5.39.71.183.25565: UDP, length 72
```

Which is above the 3/second limit specified on `nft`. The `nft` rules are:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }

        iifname lo accept

        tcp dport 1935 ct state new log prefix "[RTMP]: " accept
        tcp dport 443 ct state new log prefix "[HTTPS]: " accept
        tcp dport 3478 ct state new log prefix "[STUN TCP]: " limit rate 5/second accept
        tcp dport 5349 ct state new log prefix "[STUN TLS]: " limit rate 5/second accept
        ########################################################################
        ####### These two rules are where it is not behaving as intended #######
        udp dport 3478 log prefix "[STUN UDP]: " limit rate 3/second accept
        udp dport 3478 log prefix "[STUN UDP THIS RULE]: " limit rate over 3/second drop
        ########################################################################
        ip saddr E.F.G.H ct state new log prefix "[Some server that is allowed]: " accept
        udp dport 5060 ct state new log prefix "[SIP UDP]: " accept
        tcp dport 5060 ct state new log prefix "[SIP TCP]: " accept
        tcp dport 5061 ct state new log prefix "[SIP TLS]: " accept
        udp dport { 5000-31000 } ct state new log prefix "[RTP]: " accept
        ip saddr 0.0.0.0 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport { 67, 68 } ct state new drop

    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
    }
}
```

There are some additional rules because there are some other services running, but I faced this problem even when the other services using the other ports were stopped.

The strangest thing to me is that there is only one mention about these packets on `dmesg`:

```
[4151543.207466] [STUN UDP]: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:d4:c1:9e:0b:4d:c0:08:00 SRC=5.39.71.183 DST=A.B.C.D LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=31022 PROTO=UDP SPT=25565 DPT=3478 LEN=28
```

It's very likely I'm not understanding something, either about `nftables`, STUN, both or something else. The questions:

1. Is the order of the rules wrong? Like, the STUN UDP rules should be before the `ct state vmap` line?
2. With the `nftables` rule setting the 3/second limit, with no consideration about the state of the packet, shouldn't it be processed on every packet received on port 3478?

Or maybe it's something else I have not identified that is making the `nftables` limit not be applied.

System information:

```
OS: Debian 11
coturn version: 4.5.2-3 from the Debian repository.
nftables version: v0.9.8 (E.D.S.) from the Debian repository.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your *tcpdump* capture is considered by Netfilter as a **single flow**: each packet match the same dual-way *conntrack* 5-uple (here: udp,5.39.71.183,25565,A.B.C.D,3478) . So once the very first packet of this flow, by definition in state `new`, is accepted with the limiting rule, every other packets of the same flow, which are in Netfilter's *conntrack* in state `established`, are accepted by the very first short-circuiting rule:

> ```
> ct state vmap { established : accept, related : accept, invalid : drop }
> ```

While you witness this only for UDP, TCP should behave the same, but I guess it's easier to do DDoS with UDP than TCP (no spoofing with TCP etc.).

You should move limitation-related rules before the first short-circuiting rule.